# legacy-install-failure during installing bulkvis

Tags: python, pip, numpy

I am trying to setup [bulkvis](https://github.com/LooseLab/bulkvis) and when I enter the following command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/LooseLab/bulkvis.git@2.0
```

I get the errors below:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
      
      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> numpy
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Could you please help how to get rid of them?

I am using ubuntu 22.04.02, pip 22.0.2 and python 3.10.6.